# Node.js requires callback functions but got a [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to do upload using node.js.

```
router.post('/image', [ multer(), function(req, res) {
  var file = req.files.file;
  console.log(file);
  res.end();
}]);
```

What's wrong with above code? I'm getting error of

```
Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as post]
```

Comment: your usage of `multer()` doesn't look much like any usage in the [documentation for multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you're following an older tutorial that uses `multer`'s older API. The API changed ~v1.0.0 and you can find an example of the new API [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage). For example:

```
 var upload = multer();
 router.post('/image', [ upload.any(), function(req, res) {
   var file = req.files.file;
   console.log(file);
   res.end();
 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong about router parameters & multer usage. You should see [multer documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Here is an example to help you fit your code.

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

router.post('/image', upload.single("image"), function(req, res) {
    var file = req.file;
    console.log(file);
    res.end();
}]);
```

Comment: There is an extra square bracket on your last line. Thank you though.